# How to implement SwipeListView with two button at right?

Tags: android, swipe

I want to implement the SwipeListView like below image, I have download github code [SwipeListView](https://github.com/huazhiyuan2008/SwipeListView) for that and make changes in it, But it fails what I want to implement

[image]

I want to implement that when user swipe listitem to left , two or three buttons should be display at right side

I make changes in above demo like below code

com.aug.swipe/MainActivity.java

```
protected View generateRightView(final int position) {

        LinearLayout lnv_right = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutParams lnv_params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lnv_right.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView deleteView = new TextView(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 100);
        deleteView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        deleteView.setText("delete ");
        deleteView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        deleteView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#12c2c2"));
        deleteView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "del " + mList.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        TextView editView = new TextView(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams edt_lp = new LayoutParams(200, 100);
        editView.setLayoutParams(edt_lp);
        editView.setText("delete ");
        editView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        editView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#12c2c2"));
        editView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "del " + mList.get(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        lnv_right.addView(editView);
        lnv_right.addView(deleteView);

        lnv_right.setLayoutParams(lnv_params);

        return lnv_right;

    }
```

But this is not working , need any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code instead your code:

```
LayoutParams lnv_params = new LayoutParams(400, 100);
```